# javascript: Change the underscores with the input values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the underscores in paragraph text with the input values. I tried to split the whole paragraph and change each underscore with the input values.But the result is again the array, which I have to "build" as a paragraph again. Are there any other ways to change the underscores with the values? Here is the code   [Example HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/aad6b0kn/)

```
function myFunc() {
  var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("inputCity").value;
  var day = document.getElementById("inputDay").value;
  var month = document.getElementById("inputMonth").value;
  var year = document.getElementById("inputYear").value;
  var changeSTR = document.getElementById("resultTXT").innerHTML.toString();
  var words = changeSTR.split(/[ ,.]+/);

  words[3] = name;
  words[11] = city;
  words[16] = day;
  words[17] = month;
  words[19] = year;

  var resultSTR = words.toString();
  alert(resultSTR);
}
```

Comment: What about `words.join('')`?

Comment: join will give me just a full string, without any spaces dots that are placed in the main text. I want just replace underscores with the inputs

Comment: Just place your underscores in `<span>` tags and give each of those spans their own individual id and alter the text of those.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `<span></span>`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aad6b0kn/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultSTR = words.join(' ');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aad6b0kn/1/

Comment: I understand the words.join(' '); but is that the only way? also I want to add dots at some places to make filled text identical to original one with underscores. and is the "replacing" logic correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the whole paragraph into an array, just give each underscore section a `<span>` tag with its on id so you can change the content of those instead. I'd recommend using jQuery for this. Here's an example below to use it. Also note, the button itself is an `<input type="button">` instead of a standard `<button>` tag.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#change").click(function() {
    $("#name1").text($("#namespace").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>My name is <span id="name1">___</span></p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="namespace"></input>
</form>
<input type="button" id="change" value="Change Name"></input>
```